# Take data from another field in yii2 form

Tags: php, yii2

I'm making a form with yii2, now I have two field:

```
 <?php echo $form->field($model, 'Protocol')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->dropDownList(
                    array("rtsp://"=>"rtsp","rsmt://"=>"rsmt","http://"=>"http"),     // Flat array ('id'=>'label')
                    ['prompt'=>'Select']     // options
                ); ?>

 <?php echo $form->field($model, 'url')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]); ?>
```

They look like this: [image: form]

How can I take the selection from Protocol's drop down list and automatically add it to the below URL field? Like this: [image] I type the `http://` in the field manually, is there anyway I can make it automatic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `onchange` event in your `'protocol'` dropdownList. show below code

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'Protocol')->dropdownList(["rtsp://"=>"rtsp","rsmt://"=>"rsmt","http://"=>"http"], [
    'onchange'=>'$( "#'.Html::getInputId($model, 'url').'").val($(this).val());'

    ]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'url')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]);
?>
```

Comment: Can I use that code for normal text field `textInput(['maxlength' => true])`?

Comment: @ProudNoob. Yes you can, just need id or name of textInput().

Comment: @InsaneSkull I meant use the code `'onchange'=>'$( "#'.Html::getInputId($model, 'url').'").val($(this).val());'` to this field `<?= $form->field($model, 'ip')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]);
?>`

I tried to insert the coed into the ip field but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ProudNoob. Didn't get you?